# Shorewall reporting martians

Tags: networking, firewall, shorewall

Running Shorewall v5.0.14.1 on Fedora Server 4.8.15-200.fc24.x86_64 configured with two interfaces (br0 and team0). Interface br0 connects to Internet while  the team0 interface connects wireless local devices (LAN) (printers, tablets, roku, etc.). The team device is configured for loadbalancing using two nics. Additionally, DHCP and DNS answer requests on team0 interface. Shorewall flags broadcasts as martians. Intermittently devices sending requests to  DHCP are also flagged as martians. Sample of messages appear as follows (first is broadcast; second is device requesting IP address:

> Jan  9 15:42:09 roxie kernel: IPv4: martian source 10.0.2.255 from     10.0.2.254, on dev team0
>
> Jan  9 15:42:09 roxie kernel: ll header: 00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff         00 16 3e 3c 20 a1 08 00        ........>< ..
>
> Jan  9 15:51:04 roxie kernel: IPv4: martian source 10.0.2.1 from 10.0.2.254, on dev team0

Interface Info:
Shorewall Interface: wr0 team0      dhcp,tcpflags,upnp,maclist,nets=10.0.2.0/24,physical=team0,routeback,routefilter,arp_filter=0,logmartians

ip link show team0 (ip address - 10.0.2.254)
6: team0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:3c:20:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0
DEVICE="team0"
DEVICETYPE="Team"
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.0.2.254
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": {"name": "loadbalance"}, "tx_hash": ["eth", "ipv4"], "tx_balancer": {"name": "basic"}}'
MTU="9000"
IPV4INIT=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=team0
ONBOOT="yes

My question(s): Is there a configuration error in device team0 shorewall interface configuration causing this behavior? Is there a troubleshooting method to isolate this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your interface configuration, e.g. `ip a`

Comment: Line near bottom beginning with "Interface" is team0 entry in shorewall's interface file.

Comment: You made a lot of statements but haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Sorry you're right. Wondered if team0 shorewall interface looks misconfigured and causing martian reporting. If interface is not misconfigured, need assistance isolating / troubleshooting described behavior.

Comment: You could start by providing the information I asked for.